# How to find groups of individuals who attended multiple events together?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a table with a list of Attendees (Attendee IDs) and Events (Event IDs). Each Event has several Attendees, and several Attendees went to multiple Events. I need to:

1. find groups of four attendees who attended three or more of the same events together;
2. count the number of events the group(s) attended together, and
3. find the relevant Event IDs.

**Example input table (CSV):**

```
Event ID,Attendee ID
E1,A1
E1,A2
E1,A21
E1,A22
E1,A23
E1,A24
E2,A7
E2,A1
E2,A2
E2,A21
E2,A22
E2,A23
E2,A24
E3,A14
E3,A1
E3,A2
E3,A21
E3,A22
E3,A23
E3,A24
E3,A18
E3,A19
E4,A20
E4,A21
E4,A22
E4,A23
E4,A24
```

**Example desired output (in any format):**

- One group of four Attendees (A21, A22, A23, A24) attended four Events together (E1, E2, E3, E4).

**Feedback requested**: Not looking for specific code, but interested in feedback regarding the best approach to performing this analysis using Excel VBA (i.e. starting point, strategy, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this is an exercise and you are not interested in an alternative approach, but should someone else stumble across this post in earnest the easiest solution may be to apply a PivotTable:

[image: SO27698305 example]

Comment: beat me to it this time.  you could either set it up the way you have it, or you could put the event in the rows (with attendee), but make sure event is grouped ahead of attendee; i.e. event is listed on top.  That way it will just give you a list, as opposed to this grid like structure.  personally I tend to use the list structure more than this grid structure.

Comment: oh, then this may be a better way to look at it.  i thought he meant he wanted to know which event had 4+ attendies; that way you could just set it up all as a row.  i don't mind the sub totalls.. i think there are ways to remove them though, but i like them so i keep them there

Comment: on the topic of sub totals, one thing i usually do is i change the format of the pivot table, so that the rows w/ sub totals have a different color / color shade than the values that compose it.  makes it easier to read, and looks kinda nice too

Comment: Thank you both for responding! I'm definitely interested in alternative approaches. The pivot table works great for the example data. I apologize for not clarifying in my question, I'm looking for a more automated solution that can be used across thousands of events and attendees. My understanding is after creating a pivot table you would need to do a manual/visual search for groups. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: well IDK, good you read it right because I didn't.  I think the way you have it set up should still do sub totals (at the bottom though, and in the totals column at the right).  to do the highlighting, pivot table tools => design =>  click down twice, and pick anything on that row.  those are the ones i tend to use (medium 1 - 6)

Comment: @mcfupdates pivot tables are pretty powerful, IMO one of the best features in excel.  i don't know what you mean by "manual or visual search for groups".  but you can set the PT up so that it automatically takes a range of data (you could even do this w/ VBA), and just refresh the PT.  when you refresh it it recalculates everything (assuming you want the same formatting every time).  but be careful the input data to the pivot table is correct, and that it is capturing everything (if the input data / size will change)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `pnuts` the table does not uniquely identify `E1,E2,E3` as having `A1,A2,A21,A22` and `E1,E2,E3` as having `A2,A21,A22,A23` as meeting the criteria.

mc, I might do something like:

1. build a dictionary of `{event}"E2" {string of all attendants}"A1,A2,A7,A21,A22…"` for each unique event.
2. build a list of attendees (nonrepeating).
3. from the attendee list build combinations of four attendee strings `("A1,A2,A21,A22"…)` and seek for substring in dictionary
4. record results where 3 or more events occur for matching strings in a table.